# React Query with Expo Router

Tags: react-native, expo-router

i am starting a react native project and using expo router.
I'm trying to use react query and I noticed that the expo router doesn't have a root file for the QueryClientProvider to wrap. Hence I am not able to configure react query. I tried some other ways and it didn't work.
I did a search and didn't see anyone writing about this topic. If anyone has done it before, please help me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You have a good question, but you should be more specific and give more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the layout files:

1. Create an Expo Router app `npx create-expo-app@latest --template tabs`
2. Add your `{yourProject}/app/_layout.tsx` here you can add your providers

```js
import FontAwesome from '@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import { DarkTheme, DefaultTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import { SplashScreen, Stack } from 'expo-router';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useColorScheme } from 'react-native';

export {
  // Catch any errors thrown by the Layout component.
  ErrorBoundary,
} from 'expo-router';

export const unstable_settings = {
  // Ensure that reloading on `/modal` keeps a back button present.
  initialRouteName: '(tabs)',
};

export default function RootLayout() {
  const [loaded, error] = useFonts({
    SpaceMono: require('../assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf'),
    ...FontAwesome.font,
  });

  // Expo Router uses Error Boundaries to catch errors in the navigation tree.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) throw error;
  }, [error]);

  return (
    <>
      {/* Keep the splash screen open until the assets have loaded. In the future, we should just support async font loading with a native version of font-display. */}
      {!loaded && <SplashScreen />}
      {loaded && <RootLayoutNav />}
    </>
  );
}

function RootLayoutNav() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <>
      {/* Add your react-query provider */}
      <ThemeProvider value={colorScheme === 'dark' ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
        <Stack>
          <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          <Stack.Screen name="modal" options={{ presentation: 'modal' }} />
        </Stack>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```